# Rails 4 PUT link auto refresh with ajax

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

In my current controller I have a method that updates the model link with 1 point:

```
def modify_points
  @link = Link.find(params[:id])
  @link.points += 1


  respond_to do |format|
    if @link.update_attributes(params[:points])
      format.html { redirect_to root_path }
      format.js
    else
   format.js
    end
  end
end
```

In my routes:

```
put 'links/:id/vote' => 'links#modify_points', :as => 'modify_points'
```

And my view:

```
<%= link_to 'Vote', modify_points_path(link), :remote => true, :method => :put, :id => "modify_points" %>
```

But whenever I press the link, I can only see updated information after refreshing the page.

EDIT:
I created an index.js.erb file in the links view folder directory with the following:

```
$('#modify_points').update("<%= escape_javascript(render(@link)) %>");
```

Im getting this error in the console when link is pressed:

```
PUT http://localhost:3000/links/1/vote 500 (Internal Server Error) jquery.js?body=1:8707
send jquery.js?body=1:8707
jQuery.extend.ajax jquery.js?body=1:8137
$.rails.rails.ajax jquery_ujs.js?body=1:74
$.rails.rails.handleRemote jquery_ujs.js?body=1:150
(anonymous function) jquery_ujs.js?body=1:300
jQuery.event.dispatch jquery.js?body=1:5096
elemData.handle
```

Comment: Of, course, you should create js view with code, that would be reloaded some partial or element. However there is no view that important also.

Comment: @zishe Can you explain what you mean?

Comment: You should create file in view directory named by your action - `modify_points.js.erb` (for `erb`), and write there like: `$('#points_container').html("<%= escape_javascript(render template: 'model/list') %>")`, or some code that would change points value on new one. So, it can't be done automatically.

Comment: For, example [this](https://github.com/zishe/rails_book_reader/blob/master/app/views/books/upload_book.js.erb) you can check controller and views if you don't understand something.

Comment: @zishe I put this $('#points_container').html("<%= escape_javascript(render template: 'links/index') %>") but dosent do anything

Comment: See [this video](http://railscasts.com/episodes/205-unobtrusive-javascript) i think it should help. You also should create partial witch i called `links/index` for your case.

Comment: @zishe I get this error in console `jQuery.extend.ajax jquery.js?body=1:8137
$.rails.rails.ajax jquery_ujs.js?body=1:74
$.rails.rails.handleRemote jquery_ujs.js?body=1:150
(anonymous function) jquery_ujs.js?body=1:300
jQuery.event.dispatch jquery.js?body=1:5096
elemData.handle`

Comment: update post with this information.

Comment: Why `index.js.erb` it should be named like your action - `modify_points.js.erb`. And it's not enough, you should create some partial with list of links, that should be updated. It calls Unobtrusive JavaScript, you should deal with it, i cant say step by step what to do.

Comment: @DillonRaphael did you manage to fix this issue? If so, can you please post the answer?

Comment: @Zippie still havn't been able to get an answer. Although I think my best bet is to learn something like Angular.

Comment: @DillonRaphael if you have it open sourced somewhere, like hosted on github i would be glad to take a look at it